# Why can't I refresh the list of packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager

This might be a duplicate, but I can't find a solution in other posts.

Whenever I try to update I get this message:

```
ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR###ERROR
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/listspackages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_free_i18n_Translation-en, 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried runnig this in the terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

It doesn't work at all. I cant even open the software sources and "sudo apt-get check" gives me this message:
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_free_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

**UPDATE: solution for me was to remove the medibuntu-keyring through synaptic manager and removed mediubuntu from the software sources too manually. This seems to have solved the problem. The update manager doesnt give me any error messages anymore.**

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -lR /var/lib/apt`

Comment: @SirCharlo I have just removed the medibuntu-keyring through synaptic manager and removed mediubuntu from the software sources too manually. This seems to have solved the problem. The update manager doesnt give me any error messages anymore.